# Unknown token with sentencepiece

Tags: nlp, tokenize

I have a huge corpus of text that I have trained sentencepiece on. I want to tokenize this text and pass it to word2vec for learning word embeddings.

However, when I run sp.EncodeAsPieces(text), if there exists a word that is not in the sp vocab, it does not return < unk > . It instead keeps the word as is. This is a problem for running word2vec because these tokens will not be treated as < unk >.

The only solution I have found so far is to use sp.EncodeAsIds, which tokenizes the text to numbers, and unknown words are tokenized to 0. But I lose the readability that comes with EncodeAsPieces. Any way to use EncodeAsPieces and tokenize words not in vocab to < unk >?

Comment: What about generating the indices and then converting then back to the tokens?

Comment: Yes, this is what I do at present, but I was thinking a direct method if exists would be faster.